Does this op amp connected to an LC tank amplify its resonant frequency?
The circuit below has a resonant frequency at 159.155 kHz and should amplify it:

That's exactly what this sweep predicts:

But,even when setting V1 to 159.155 kHz the transient analysis shows no amplification, except for clipping  at the bottom (which happens at any frequency):

Where's the 6dB of amplification predicted?

Update
Moving the signal well within the rails, based on Andy's suggestions, solves the clipping but still gets zero amplification:


There's no loss indicated for L1 or C1; try a finer resolution sweep, I expect you'll find the true peak is much higher than 6dB.

The lower point of resistor R1 should be wired to a 4.5 V voltage. Voltage generator DC = 4.5 V too.

What you said I suggested is false. I suggested using a bipolar supply. Then you can keep the resistor tied to 0 volts and use a simple AC input signal with no DC offset. Walk first then run.

R1 return point is irrelevant as inductor DCR is close to zero (assuming no parasitic properties entered) and the op-amp has more than enough output current capacity to supply the resistor.

The Q of your circuit is "infinite" ... so you can't see the variation of the gain ... Add a resistor series with the inductor ... and you will see this peak.

The filter, as designed, is too "selective".
So, you can't see the amplification at resonance ...
Insert a resistor series with the inductor in the schematic, and now the peak is visible.


Does this op amp connected to an LC tank amplify its resonant frequency?

Yes, it does ...
But if you suppress this resistor, the peak (very narrow) is "infinite" and you should have a "frequency" at the input with "many" decimals to see it, otherwise the gain is effective "1" (0 dB).
This circuit is not "well" designed.
It should be something like this :

UPDATE
NB: Depending on "how" you simulate, you shall find some "inconsistent" figure.
Simulated with the same values of internal parameters, except the "full time" simulation.
I simulated for 1 ms (from zero states) and then continued simulation during another 1 ms (saving the last state of variables).
I simulated also during 2 ms (from zero state).
If one compares the two simulations, one will see an "issue" with the second half simulation (black circled).
Some other "issues" may occur, eventually "repeated" as "AM modulation".
One must be very careful with "simulations".


I added the R2 as you said, and experimented with many resistances, but did not get any significant amplification in the transient analysis.  The AC sweep shows 3dB at 159.0 without any resistor.  Adding a 1milliOhm does nothing appreciable.  Adding a 1 Ohm removes almost all amplification at any frequency

You are right. This circuit is not well "designed". The inductor should be higher ... and the capacitor "lower". The R2 I added is for explaining theoretically the behavior, but really, it does "nothing" in this context.

Miultiply L by 1000 and divide C by the same value. R2=10. This should be ok.

Antonio: Multiplying L and dividing C solved it! It does develop, for some reason, an unexplainable AM envelope, similar to that posted here.

This phenomenon appears when the "numerical" values used in the simulator are "inconsistent" with normal use. I will show it in my answer. It is a problem with the "simulation", not with the simulator or with the model used.

You need to understand how the SPICE models of the inductor and capacitor are constructed. LTspice adds a loss component to inductors and capacitors (I don't know the values) which aids in keeping the solver from mathematically blowing up for most circuits. These loss components are usually better than a real part can offer. These parameters are controllable (right-click on the component).
If you do an impedance plot (right-hand graph) of the parallel LC combination, you'll see the loss component show up which limits the impedance of the resonant circuit. For the 1 uH & 1 uF combination, the circuit has an equivalent of about 1 k ohm parallel loss component. The 100 nF & 10 uH combination, the equivalent parallel loss component is about 100 k ohms. If you use values of 100 nF & 10 uH in your circuit, you can get a gain of 40 dB as shown below which is consistent with the impedance plots.
Note, the opamp is LTspice's universal opamp with the GBW set to 100 MHz and the input resistance set to 50 G ohms. The universal opamp is a behavioral model which does not need a power supply, thus, wild voltages are possible with this model.


You need to power your op-amp from bipolar supplies <-- that's the first thing and, that's why it's clipping at the bottom. I expect that once you have done this you will get a significant improvement in the transient response.
More detail: the op-amp data sheet explains that the input common-mode range is +/-3.5 volts on a supply regime of +/-5 volts so, if you had a supply of 10 volts and 0 volts, the actual valid input range would be from +1.5 volts to +8.5 volts.
Same story for the output voltage swing; you basically can't get to within a volt or so of either supply rail.

Andy, the sine wave has a 2V offset, so the signal is entirely within the rails of the op-amp.  Since ground is relative, isn't that the same thing as using bipolar supplies?  Also: If that's the cause, why does the AC sweep still show 6 dB of amplification?

@SRobertJames that isn't sufficient for this particular op-amp. See my detail edits in my answer. The AC sweep usually takes the liberty of applying optimal DC conditions to a circuit and hence can overcome some circuit problems.

Precisely, SPICE takes the DC operating conditions as given (which includes both sources' DC values here) and linearizes the circuit around that operating point. This is like running a transient simulation with arbitrarily small amplitude, if it were evaluated at arbitrarily high precision (since, if you actually tried this, you'd see truncation and rounding errors manifest as a noisy output), the AC signal measured, and repeated for each frequency sampled.

Andy, can you see the updated circuit I posted, which moves well within the rails but still has the same zero amplification.

Let it build up over many, many more cycles. This is how tuned circuits acquire significant energy. You still have the resistor tied to gnd too. Use split supplies to see what happens.

@SRobertJames if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.
